# How to exclude particular div from jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a swipe menu on left hand side of my mobile web, here is the menu html

```
<div class="swipe" style="height: 433px; left: 0px;">
    <div class="swipe-menu">

<div class="nav-container-mobile">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="sf-menu-block">
                    <div id="menu-icon" class="">categories</div>
                    <ul class="sf-menu-phone" style="display: none;">
                        <li class="level0 nav-1 first level-top parent"><a href="http://example.com/products.html" class="level-top"><span>product</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
        <a href="http://example.com/" title="home" class="home-link">home</a>
        <ul class="links">
                        <li class="first"><a href="http://example.com/customer/account/" title="account">My account</a></li>
                                <li class=" last"><a href="http://example.com/customer/account/login/" title="login" onclick="return false;">Login</a></li>
            </ul>


        <div class="footer-links-menu"> 
            <ul>
<li><a href="http://example.com/about">test</a></li>
<li><a href="http://example.com/customer-service">test</a></li>
<li><a href="http://example.com/template-settings">test</a></li>
<li class="last privacy"><a href="http://example.com/privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode">priva</a></li>
</ul>  
            <ul class="links-2">
    <li class="first"><a href="http://example.com/catalog/seo_sitemap/product/">Product Sitemap</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com/catalog/seo_sitemap/category/">Category Sitemap</a></li>

    <li><a href="http://example.com/sales/guest/form/">Order</a></li>
</ul>        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this js will toggle slide in out,

```
    function swipe_animate_true(){
        jQuery('.swipe-control').addClass('active');
        jQuery('.swipe').stop(true).animate({'left':'0'},300);
    }
    function swipe_animate_false(){
        jQuery('.swipe-control').removeClass('active');
        jQuery('.swipe').stop(true).animate({'left':'-237px'},400);
    }
    jQuery('.swipe-control').click(function(){
        swipe_animate_true();
        mini_form_hide();
        if(jQuery(this).parents('body').hasClass('ind')){
            jQuery(this).parents('body').removeClass('ind');
            swipe_animate_false()
            return false
        }
        else{
            jQuery(this).parents('body').addClass('ind');
            swipe_animate_true()
            return false
        }
    })
```

i want to exclude .sf-menu-block which will be toggled as slide out, i had tried

```
jQuery('.swipe:not(.sf-menu-block)').stop(true).animate({'left':'-237px'},400);
```

}

but it is not working, anyone knows how to do that?

[image]

------------------update--------------------
tried

```
jQuery(".swipe  > :not(.nav-container-mobile)").stop(true).animate({'left':'-237px'},400);
```

but this will make top-left button not able to slide out the menu.

Comment: i have a image to explain what i'm asking

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking; what do you mean, “exclude” the element - exclude it from what? The animation? You can of course not have the ancestor element move around, but have a descendant _not_ do the same thing. If you want a descendant element to “stay” while the ancestor is moving, then you would have to apply the reverse movement on the descendant. // `.swipe:not(.sf-menu-block)` makes no sense of course - you only have one element with the class `slide`, and that element does not also have the class `sf-menu-block` - so this is the same as if you just used `.swipe`

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    Sandip
    <div class="sf-menu-block">
        my div
    </div>
</div>
```

You can remove div tag with match class "sf-menu-block" with javascript as per your requirement as below:

```
var divBlock = document.getElementsByClassName("sf-menu-block")[0];
divBlock.outerHTML = '';
```

**To Exclue any element in JQuery** for your case:

```
$("div").not($(".sf-menu-block"))
```

If you tried with `$("div").length` it give **2** as length , while `$("div").not($(".sf-menu-block")).length` will give you **1**

In your syntax may be:

```
jQuery('.swipe').not(jQuery('.sf-menu-block')).stop(true).animate({'left':'-237px'},400);
```

Comment: exclude != remove

Comment: I have update answer to exclue element in jquery

Comment: tried jQuery('.swipe').not(jQuery(".sf-menu-block")).stop(true).animate({'left':'-237px'},400); , not working